# AngularJS - Push data from inputs to array within particular object

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have an array with different employee objects, each of which have their own nested payments array inside, like below:

```
var employees = [
{
    id: '1',
    icon: 'img/NC.png',
    iconAlt: 'N C Image',
    title: 'Mr',
    firstName: 'N',
    lastName: 'C',
    dateOfBirth: '01/01/1900',
    niNumber: 'JZ123456D',
    jobTitle: 'Web Developer',
    department: 'Development',
    joinDate: '18/04/2017',
    leaveDate: '18/04/2017',
    email: 'user@mail.com',
    phonePrimary: '0123 456789',
    phoneSecondary: '0123 456789',
    menu: 'nickCookMenu',
    payments: [
        {
            id: 1,
            code: 'TEST',
            paymentType: '',
            hours: '',
            zeroiseHours: false,
            partPay: false,
            rate: '',
            employerPercentage: '',
            pay: '',
            paidPer: '',
            fromDate: '',
            sequence: '',
            employerPension: '',
            csaReference: '',
            suspend: false,
            netToGross: false,
            requiredTotal: '',
            paidToDate: '',
            protectedNet: '',
            arrearsCarried: ''
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            code: 'TEST',
            paymentType: '',
            hours: '',
            zeroiseHours: false,
            partPay: false,
            rate: '',
            employerPercentage: '',
            pay: '',
            paidPer: '',
            fromDate: '',
            sequence: '',
            employerPension: '',
            csaReference: '',
            suspend: false,
            netToGross: false,
            requiredTotal: '',
            paidToDate: '',
            protectedNet: '',
            arrearsCarried: ''
        },
    ]
},
]
```

-

I've fetched the values of various inputs in a form like below, and want to add this data as a new payment into the particular employee's payments array.

```
    if(!error) {
        var employeePaymentFormData = [
            {
                code: angular.element('#employeePaymentForm input#paymentCodeInput').val(),
                paymentType: angular.element('#employeePaymentForm input#paymentTypeSelect').val(),
                hours: angular.element('#employeePaymentForm input#paymentHoursInput').val(),
                zeroiseHours: angular.element('#employeePaymentForm input#zeroiseHoursCheckbox').val(),
                partPay: angular.element('#employeePaymentForm input#paryPayCheckbox').val(),
                rate: angular.element('#employeePaymentForm input#paymentRateInput').val(),
                employerPercentage: angular.element('#employeePaymentForm input#employerPercentageInput').val(),
                pay: angular.element('#employeePaymentForm input#paymentPayInput').val(),
                paidPer: angular.element('#employeePaymentForm input#paidPerInput').val(),
                fromDate: angular.element('#employeePaymentForm input#fromDateInput').val(),
                sequenceInput: angular.element('#employeePaymentForm input#sequenceInput').val(),
                employerPension: angular.element('#employeePaymentForm input#employerPensionInput').val(),
                csaReference: angular.element('#employeePaymentForm input#csaReferenceInput').val(),
                suspendPayment: angular.element('#employeePaymentForm input#suspendPaymentCheckbox').val(),
                netToGross: angular.element('#employeePaymentForm input#netToGrossCheckbox').val(),
                requiredTotal: angular.element('#employeePaymentForm input#requiredTotalInput').val(),
                paidToDate: angular.element('#employeePaymentForm input#paidToDateInput').val(),
                protectedNet: angular.element('#employeePaymentForm input#protectedNetInput').val(),
                arrearsCarried: angular.element('#employeePaymentForm input#arrearsCarriedInput').val(),
            }
        ]
    }
```

This is all done in an employee details state, which has data passed into it for the particular employee only, so this may help in identifying the id of the employee to push the data to.

Comment: please clarify the question

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you want to add form data to payments array of a specific employee?

First you need to get employee_id. After you got that, you could do:

```
var someEmployeeId = 1; // get it from route, or w/e

employees.forEach(function(employee){
    if (employee.id === someEmployeeId){
        employee.payments.push(employeePaymentFormData);
    }
});
```